# iOSでURLスキームで地図アプリ（GoogleMaps）を開き、複数の経由地を設定したルート案内をする方法について

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, google-maps

```
let urlStr:String = "comgooglemaps-x-callback://" + "?f=d&saddr=35.681298, 139.766268&daddr=35.658598, 139.745454" + "&x-success=sourceapp://?resume=true&x-source=AirApp"

UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:urlStr)!)
```

上記のようにURLスキームで、東京駅から東京タワーへのルート案内を行うことはできるのですが、途中で別の地点（六本木ヒルズ）などを経由するルート案内を行うことはできないでしょうか？

経由地を設定したルート案内（カーナビ）ができるのであれば、GoogleMapsにはこだわらず、AppleのMapやYahooのものでも良いのですが、、、

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

カーナビのような細やかなものではないですが、Google Maps Directions API のWayPointsで大まかにはできる気がします。

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints